# Windows file share - How to check log who has accessed what in my system

Tags: windows-7

By mistake i shared my "User" group of system and which allowed everyone to access my folder under - users/XXXX/desktop...
  Is there any way to check the logs to identify who has access my desktop items or tried to download my confidential information from Desktop ?

Your help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess net view can help you (see http://ss64.com/nt/net_share.html)

Comment: Thanks Mp. but i am looking for something somewhere log that system "X" has accessed my folder on desktop items. or some information of data transfer by that system etc

Comment: Perhaps you can look to this blog http://www.neondemon.com/archives/how-to-monitor-file-and-folder-access-on-a-windows-file-server it describe how log future access, but not past ones...